# Surface integral over a rectangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate 
$$ \iint_S \vec{v} . \vec{n} dS$$

for $\vec{v} = (x+y, -2y - 1, z)$ and $S$ the rectangle of vertices $(1,0,1),(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)$ and $\vec{n}$ points in the opposite direction of the origin

**My attempt**:

The surface $S$ can be parametrized as $\sigma(u,v) = (u, -u+1, v)$ for $(u,v) \in [0,1] \times [0,1]$'correct? The normal vector will be (1,1,0) and evaluating the integral, I got $-1$. But the answer is $-\sqrt{2}$! Since the integral is correct (I've checked in wolfram the calculus), what I did wrong?

thanks in advance!

Comment: so your sure its $-\sqrt{2}$ ?

Comment: $-1$ is correct. A value of $-\sqrt 2$ is accounting for the length of the normal vector one too many times.

Comment: Ok thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j})$ as it must be a unit vector, so
$$\mathbf{v}\cdot \mathbf{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y-1)$$ parameterise the surface by $$x=u$$
$$y=1-u$$
$$z=v$$
Then the formula for the surface differential is $|\mathbf{r}_u \times \mathbf{r}_u | dudv=\sqrt{2}dudv$ (which cancels with the constant in the normalization of the normal vector)
So we have $$\int_0^1\int_0^1 (u-(1-u) -1 )dudv=-1$$
with no guarantees that I didnt make a mistake.

Comment: Apostol defines the surface integral as $\vec{v}(x,y,z) . (D_u \times D_v)$ where $D_u$ is the vector of the derivatives of the surface in relation to $u$ and $D_v$ in relation of $v$. So it is not unit necessarily.

Comment: Yes I remember, that the vector and surface normalizations cancel. But I still cannot get your answer.